# HDP 315 | Hive DDL Query issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, ambari, hdp

Installed HDP 3.1.5,  and enabled KERBEROS security. 
In Hive normal create table is working fine. But when I'm trying to create any role getting below error. Please suggest the solution.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://host> create role userRole;
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hive_20200320085236_d9a4f82e-dab8-4952-aa53-da11a1cda4b6): create role userRole
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20200320085236_d9a4f82e-dab8-4952-aa53-da11a1cda4b6); Time taken: 0.021 seconds
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20200320085236_d9a4f82e-dab8-4952-aa53-da11a1cda4b6): create role bdauserRole
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. createRole not implemented in FallbackHiveAuthorizer
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20200320085236_d9a4f82e-dab8-4952-aa53-da11a1cda4b6); Time taken: 0.02 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. createRole not implemented in FallbackHiveAuthorizer (state=08S01,code=1)
```